# In flex, mouseOver in TextInput Programatically using AS3?

Tags: apache-flex, mouseevent, textinput

In flex, I am able to add mouseOver ( in mx:TextInput ) event as follow: mouseOver="canvas1_mouseDownHandler(event)"

It is not the property of TextInput so how can I do it programatically in ActionScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add a listener to your text input:

```
myTextInput.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
```

Hope that helps.